Trino schema not showing tables in DBeaver after configuration
I am using Trino as my query engine and DBeaver as the IDE. I have configured the catalog correctly in Trino, and I can see the schema XX_ABC_TEST. However, when I try to query the tables or view them in DBeaver, no tables are displayed,  even though the tables exist in the XX_ABC_TEST schema in the datasource.
